# How to Make A Responsive YouTube Embed in a Grid/Column (Responsive Iframe)

Tags: css, iframe, youtube, embed, responsive

**The Problem:** I need a responsive layout (100% page width, preferably) that features an embedded YouTube video on the left and a grid of thumbnail images on the right.

I naively thought iframes behaved much like images and that they would automatically adapt the iframe height when the width changes.

Here is how I *thought* (and wanted) iframes would behave for my layout in question:
https://jsfiddle.net/5by8x44b/

Here is the result I got instead when using Iframes:

https://jsfiddle.net/hfp8mhho/

The most basic form of the code (that is more specific in the jsfiddle) looks like this:

**(HTML)**

```
<div style="border: 1px solid pink; overflow: hidden; padding:5%;">

    <div class="left_box" style="background-color:cyan;">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2ZR8Oc9hEnM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="right_box">
       <!-- Image Grid Below -->
        <!-- 1st row */ -->
        <div class="grd_sqr"></div>
        <div class="grd_sqr"></div>
        <div class="grd_sqr"></div>
        <!-- 2nd row */ -->
        <div class="grd_sqr"></div>
        <div class="grd_sqr"></div>
        <div class="grd_sqr"></div>
        <!-- 3rd row */ -->
        <div class="grd_sqr"></div>
        <div class="grd_sqr"></div>
        <div class="grd_sqr"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**(CSS)**

```
.left_box {
    float: left;
    width: 65%;

}
.right_box {
    float:right;
    width: 35%;
}

iframe {
    width: 100%;
}

img {
    width:100%;
}

.grd_sqr {
    float:left;
    width: 30%;
    padding-bottom: 33%;
    margin:1.33%;
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
}
```

If you are unclear what the difference is, resize the result window for both JSFiddle examples and the problem should be clear.

=========================================================

**Potential Solutions:** I have found articles detailing the core of this issue (responsive Iframes), most notably:

https://avexdesigns.com/responsive-youtube-embed/

https://benmarshall.me/responsive-iframes/

However, I'm using a simple float left/right layout to create the two main columns and I suspect that's why the solutions detailed in the above links don't work out for solving my problem.

I have been at this for days. Could anyone please help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this for my future website. Here's my script; I wonder what you think. It should work with any providers (youtube, vimeo, etc), preserves the original aspect ratio, and will work with any appended objects as long as you run videoIframe_MakeResponsive('youtube', '16/9') after updating the page. '16/9' is a default aspect ratio if width/height aren't specified. I hope this helps! The video will be 100% width of parent element

```js
// Greatest Common Divisor
function Math_gcd(a, b) {
    if (a<b)
        [a, b] = [b, a]
    return b ? Math_gcd(b, a%b) : a
}

// get ratio ('16/9' or something) from dimensions
function Math_ratio(width, height) {
    const gcd = Math_gcd(width, height)
    return width/gcd + '/' + height/gcd
}

// add multiple css properties
function css(element, jsonCSS) {
    for (const property in jsonCSS)
        element.style[property] = jsonCSS[property]
}

// autorun
function autorun(callback) {
    if (document.readyState != 'loading')
        callback()
    else
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback)
}

// responsive iframe
function videoIframe_MakeResponsive(provider, defaultRatio = '16/9') {
    document.querySelectorAll('iframe[src*="' + provider + '"]').forEach(iframe => {
        if (!iframe.classList.contains('videoIframeFixed')) { // fix only new iframes
            let width = iframe.getAttribute('width')
            let height = iframe.getAttribute('height')
            let aspectratio = (width && height) ? Math_ratio(width, height) : defaultRatio
            iframe.removeAttribute('width') // reset
            iframe.removeAttribute('height') // reset
            iframe.classList.add('videoIframeFixed') // for future reference
            // wrapper container
            let wrapper = document.createElement('div')
            iframe.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, iframe)
            wrapper.appendChild(iframe) // move iframe inside
            // style
            css(wrapper, {
                'width': '100%',
                'position': 'relative',
                'aspect-ratio': aspectratio
            })
            css(iframe, {
                'width': '100%',
                'height': '100%',
                'position': 'absolute'
            })
        }
    })
}

// run it on page load
autorun(function () {
    videoIframe_MakeResponsive('youtube')
    videoIframe_MakeResponsive('vimeo')
    /* ... etc ... */
})
```